# NHibernate <properties>

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, unique-constraint

I am facing problems when mapping a group of properties with the -element in nhibernate.

```
<class name="PlannedSalesInYear"
     table="tblPlannedSalesInYear"
     lazy="false" >
   <id name="_businessId"
    column="BusinessId"
    access="field">
       <generator class="assigned" />
   </id>

<properties name="UIDX_PSPerVehicleAndYear"      
             optimistic-lock="true"
            insert="true"
            update="true"
            unique="true">
  <property name="_year"
            access="field"
            column="Year"/>
  <many-to-one name="_vehicle"
               access="field"
               fetch="select"
               column="VehicleId"
               foreign-key="FK_VehicleOfPlannedSalesInYear"/>      
</properties>

<property name="_plannedSales"
          not-null="false"
          access="field"
          column="PlannedSales"/>
```

It seems as saving works but when loading the vehicle property is null and the year property is 0.

When changing the mapping and avoid the -Tag it works. Unfortunately in this case the unique index doesn't work as expeceted (Sqlite).

Changed mapping:

```
<class name="PlannedSalesInYear"
     table="tblPlannedSalesInYear"
     lazy="false" >
   <id name="_businessId"
    column="BusinessId"
    access="field">
     <generator class="assigned" />
   </id>

<property name="_plannedSales"
          not-null="false"
          access="field"
          column="PlannedSales"
          />

<property name="_year"
          access="field"
          unique-key="UIDX_PSPerVehicleAndYear"
          column="Year"/>
<many-to-one name="_vehicle"
             access="field"
             fetch="select"
             column="VehicleId"
             unique-key="UIDX_PSPerVehicleAndYear"
             foreign-key="FK_VehicleOfPlannedSalesInYear"/>
```

Does someone have any idea why the loading does not work? Or an idea why creating the unique index is buggy with the second mapping?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and after I found your example of using unique-key I was able to find a solution.

When you define your properties in the hbm file add the definition of the columns as well.

```
<property name="Year">
  <column name=Year sql-type="int" not-null="true" unique-key="UC_MY" />
</property>
<property name="Month">
  <column name=Month sql-type="tinyint" not-null="true" unique-key="UC_MY" />
</property>
```

At least that works when you have two simple properties but I guess its worth a try to check if it works with many-to-one properties too.